# Question on the Background Field Method for Non-Abelian Gauge theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, renormalization, research-level, effective-field-theory

I am reading Peskin's and Schroeder's book "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory". In Chapter 16.6 the authors use the Background Field Method to determine the $\beta$ function for a non-Abelian gauge theory. In particular, they write down the exponential of the effective action in terms of a product of determinants of operators that exist in the terms in the Faddeev-Popov Lagrangian that are quadratic in the respective fields, Eq.(16.110),

$$e^{i\Gamma[A]}=\exp\bigg[i\int d^4x\Big(-\frac{1}{4g^2}(F^a_{\mu\nu})^2+\mathcal{L}_{c.t.}\Big)\bigg]
\cdot 
\text{det}(\Delta_{G,1})^{-1/2}
\text{det}(\Delta_{r,1/2})^{+n_f/2}
\text{det}(\Delta_{G,0})^{+1}$$
where $F_{\mu\nu}^a$ is the non-Abelian gauge field strength and $\mathcal{L}_{c.t.}$ is the counter-term Lagrangian, $g$ is the non-Abelian gauge theory coupling constant, $n_f$ is the number of fermion species and $\Delta_{r,j}=-D^2+2(\frac{1}{2}F^b_{\rho\sigma}\mathcal{J}^{\rho\sigma})$ is the general covariant background-field d'Alembertian, defined for each type of field.

The next goal is to derive an expression for the effective action. The first order quantum corrections of the effective action originate from the three determinants in the expression above and each is represented by a Feynman diagram with two external legs.

**My question is regarding to these diagrams:** What do they correspond to (like if I had a physical process, i.e. a scattering, what quantity of this physical process would those diagrams be corrections to)? I guess one can think of that those diagrams are quantum corrections to the effective action. But then the question reduces to "What does the effective action describe?"

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since my dissertation was more or less on this topic 30-odd years ago, I'll just comment - without reading the referenced text - that the "background field method" is not based on splitting into low & high frequency components & integrating out the HF part. It's based on rewriting the field appearing in the path integral (here the gauge field) into two parts, the "background" and a new integration variable. Then you expand the action functional in those terms & do the integrals to 1st order, where they all come out as determinants. That gets you the 1-loop result.

Comment: ... You also do the fermion integral to the same order, producing another determinant. That gets you the effective action for the background gauge field.

Comment: Yes, @FosterBoondoggle, it was not a nice way of putting it. I totally agree with you 100%. I was just trying to sketch the procedure such that I could focus on the things I am asking, which I guess I guess is "Is the expression with $\textbf{C}_{r,j}$ s the leftovers from the background field method?"

Comment: Starting with a renormalizable lagrangian the 1-loop corrections will have the same form as the zero-th order one. For a 4-d theory of only gauge fields and fermions, the divergences are logarithmic. The calculation method doesn't get you anything different from the feynman graph expansion. It just keeps the gauge invariance explicit along the way and is much simpler to calculate than all the diagrams.